# Using ngMessage for input type number

Tags: angularjs

How to leverage the ng-message for number type?
Does ngMessage support max and min attributes? if so how can it be done?

[DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/HoN6NaQTldvAbZU8NHRi?p=preview)

Example link from angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngMessages` was officially introduced in version `1.3.0-beta.8` as a module, so you need to fix the following:

1. Use version `1.3.0-beta.8` or later (the latest is `1.3.0-beta.9` right now).
2. Include `angular-messages[.min].js` in your HTML (it is a separate script).
3. Declare `ngMessages` as a dependency of your module/app.

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dsQmwkyNO2hVkccNtaFS?p=preview)**.