# How can I validate a text field using ng-message="number" in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this input control:

```
<input ng-model="vm.loanAmount" ng-min="1" type="text" name="LoanAmount" id="LoanAmount" required>
```

Consider this validation:

```
<ng-messages for="myForm.$dirty && myForm.LoanAmount.$error" multiple>
    <ng-message when="required">
        <p>An amount is required.</p>
    </ng-message>
    <ng-message when="number">
        <p>The amount must be a valid number.</p>
    </ng-message>
    <ng-message when="min">
        <p>The amount must be greater than 0.</p>
    </ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

I need this field as a text type field, but want to use `ng-messages` module to validate it to take numbers only. How is this possible without changing the field type to number?

At the moment, the only message that successfully fires is the `required` parameter. I'd like to allow numbers only, over the value of 0.

Thanks.

Comment: Without changing the field type to number, you'll have to write your own directive. I did such a thing a year or two ago, b/c the users wanted to insert commas in large numbers. You'll basically have to validate the number-ness, min, max, etc yourself.

Comment: alternative to creating a `directive` (which is probably an elegant solution no doubt), do you think you can also consider the `ng-pattern` attribute and eval the input text string and regex for validation in the `controller`? something like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900308/angularjs-dynamic-ng-pattern-validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900308/angularjs-dynamic-ng-pattern-validation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ngMessage for input type number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407720/using-ngmessage-for-input-type-number)