# Cannot display the error message using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I could not display the error message while input field takes the invalid data using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
   <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.type.$touched && bill data.type.$invalid }">
       <input type="number"  class="form-control oditek-form"  ng-model="type" name="type" step="1" min="0" placeholder="Add Type" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/">
   </div>
   <div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.type.$error" ng-if="billdata.type.$touched">
       <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs only number(e.g-0,1..9).</p>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here I need to only give number as input. If user is entering anything rather than number it should display the error message. Here `myError` is showing the red color border on input field which is coming properly but the message is not coming which should display.

Comment: plz mark your answer if any below answers helped.

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="">
    <form name="myForm">     
   For Text  <input name="myName" ng-model="myName"  ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/" required>       
    <span style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.required">First Name is required.</span>                                                                        <span style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.pattern">Any other symbol are not allow.</span>
      
    <br />
      For Number 
      
      <input type="number" class="textbox_usr" name="txtmobno" id="txtmobno"  ng-model="txtmobno" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" required /><br />
                                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.txtmobno.$dirty && myForm.txtmobno.$invalid">
                                                                <span ng-show="myForm.txtmobno.$error.required || myForm.txtmobno.$error.number">Valid Mobile number is required</span>
                                                                <span ng-show="((myForm.txtmobno.$error.minlength || myForm.txtmobno.$error.maxlength) && myForm.txtmobno.$dirty) ">Mobile number should be 10 digits</span>
                                                            </span>
    </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-messages` div should be like following

```
<div ng-messages="billdata.type.$error" ng-show="billdata.type.$touched">
  <div ng-message when="pattern">
    <span>This field needs only number(e.g-0,1..9).</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me what versions are you using for ng-messages and angular?

Comment: Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407720/using-ngmessage-for-input-type-number

Comment: i am using angular-toastr to display messages. Along side you can also use ng-Dialogue in your controller

Comment: you did not mention that in question. And with ng-messages it is working with right versions for me.

Comment: @Rakeschand : NO i used your code but its not working.

Comment: Did you check the versions ?

Comment: i have same process on other file which is working properly but here i unable to detect the bug.